# RGoogleAnalytics: Multiple filters

Tags: r, filtering, google-analytics-api

I am trying to use multiple filters in RGoogleAnalytics packages, but they doesn't work the same way, as they do in Query Explorer.

I want to get results for Source Medium `ga:sourceMedium == google / cpc` and for nonbrand kewyords, so at the same time use filter `ga:keyword!@Peli`

My code is:

```
Init(start.date = "2016-01-01",
     end.date = "2016-03-31",
     dimensions = c("ga:yearMonth"),
     metrics = c("ga:users", "ga:sessions", "ga:costPerConversion", "ga:ItemQuantity", "ga:transactionShipping", "ga:adCost"),
     table.id = "ga:183149",
     filters = c("ga:keyword!@"brandname";ga:sourceMedium==google / cpc"),
     max.results = 9000)
```

Based on the API Info, this should do the work. And it does in the query explorer.

When I copy&paste it to R this way, returned results is 0.
When I change ; for , it returns the OR statement - summary for all transactions which are google CPC or doesn't contain brandname as keyword.

How can I adjust the filter code, to make it work the same way as it does in query explorer? So it will give me results for nonbrand adwords transactions?

Thanks!

Comment: Url encode the spaces, i.e. make it `google%20/%20cpc` in `filters`?

Comment: Works fine when using just google / cpc as filter
What I can't achieve is to process these 2 filters with AND condition instead of OR

Comment: just checked `filters = c("ga:keyword==foo;ga:sourceMedium==foo / bar")` (semicolon, AND) vs ``filters = c("ga:keyword==foo,ga:sourceMedium==foo / bar")`` (comma, OR) and both work as expected.

Comment: This way it works also for me - when I specify `filters = c("ga:keyword=="brandname";ga:sourceMedium==google / cpc")` R returns exactly what query exploerer does.
But it is because when keyword is set to brandname, there is no way how it can be anything else than google/cpc. I assume it is same in your case.
What doesn't work is when I want to make filter something is sm googlecpc AND doesn't contaion keyword.
`ga:keyword!@brandname;ga:sourceMedium==google / cpc` returns same numbers as GA. Same filter in R return just 0 for all variables. When i replace `;` with ;`; it is set to OR logic

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem today. Found the fix. Tested it for both include/exclude and exact/regex.

Translating it to your use case -

```
Init(start.date = "2016-01-01",
     end.date = "2016-03-31",
     dimensions = c("ga:yearMonth"),
     metrics = c("ga:users", "ga:sessions", "ga:costPerConversion", "ga:ItemQuantity", "ga:transactionShipping", "ga:adCost"),
     table.id = "ga:183149",
     filters = c("ga:keyword!@brandname;ga:sourceMedium==google%20/%20cpc"),
     max.results = 9000)
```

Also, the question is 11 months old. You can revert with any other fix you found to help others.